# UIPicker Not Showing Up

Tags: ios, uiimage, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView that I made programmatically but everything I made in interface builder and the picker wont show up once I run the app. It worked before I made the background in IB (which is a UIImage).Everything else shows up.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews(viewDidLoad)
{
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:picker1];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:backgroundImage];
    [backgroundImage addSubview:picker1];
}
```

I've tried all these.My brain is dead and I really just need help. Why wont my UIPickerView show up. All the needed data is there it worked before I put a background on it.Can anything be done ?

Comment: if you're sending the subview to back, would anything within that subview (your background image) be behind everything else in your image and therefore anything in front of your background (including the picker) would be obscured by everything else?  Also, make sure "`picker1`" is not null, and that the "`hidden`" bit is not set in the picker object.

Comment: Also that `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:picker1]` seems a bit redundant as your adding it to backgroundImage straight after.

Comment: No, I was just showing examples of what i have used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your data delegates is connected to the view. You can do this by going to the storyboard and clicking the Files owner and connecting the referencing outlets to the view.